# functionality for the delete

Tags: contract-development

I have the function:

```
    contract TaskContract {

      function deleteTask(uint256 taskId, bool isDeleted) external {
            if (taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender) {
                tasks[taskId].isDeleted = isDeleted;
                emit DeleteTask(taskId, isDeleted);
          }
    }
```

My question:

Is it possible to add a contract **owner** here so that he can also delete tasks along with mapped users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
contract TestContract {

     address owner;

     constructor() {
         owner = msg.sender;
     }

     function deleteTask(uint256 taskId, bool isDeleted) external {
          if (taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender || msg.sender == owner) {
              tasks[taskId].isDeleted = isDeleted;
              emit DeleteTask(taskId, isDeleted);
          }
     }
 }
```

This also checks if the `msg.sender` is also the owner of the contract, if so, he can also delete tasks along with mapped users.

Comment: Checked. Still nothing..

Comment: What i want to achieve here is to call that function from another smart contract that mapped user created. Any ideas ?